# Проблема с кодировкой CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Всем привет.
Подкинули задачку с одним древним сайтом на cakephp.
Проблема вот в чем: при редактировании информации на сайте из админ панели весь отредактированный текст на кириллице выводится знаками вопроса.

В файле database.php была строчка 'encoding' => 'windows-1251' поменял на utf-8 - не помогло
В phpmyadmin Сопоставление кодировки соединения с MySQL стоит utf8_general_ci. 
При просмотре кода страницы в браузере с формами редактирования смутила строчка:

```
<form action="/admin/mototechnics/edit/462" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MototechnicEditForm" method="post" accept-charset="windows-1251">
```

Я так понял данные передаются в кодировке 1251. Может быть в этом проблема? И как её исправить? В шаблоне странице редактирования нет строчки с атрибутом accept-charset

Answer (score 0):

Выставьте `encoding` в параметрах подключения к БД в файле **config/app.php**:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'my_app',
        'password' => 'sekret',
        'database' => 'my_app',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ]
],
```

[Документация](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration)

Comment: сейчас вроде проблема решилась таким образом: в core.php строчку Configure::write('App.encoding', 'utf-8'); поставил utf-8 вместо 1251